# Does upgrading fishing rods affect what visitors can catch?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

In the Holohouse mode, sometimes visiting members will catch fish for me. If I upgrade my fishing rod at Bloop's Fish Shop or equip a different rod, does that affect what types of fish the visiting members can catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The equipped rod affects which fish visiting members can catch.

I equipped the Beginner's Rod then waited at the House. The next 10 members that went fishing only caught Tuna, Shrimp, or Clownfish. When I equipped the Golden Rod they caught Manta Rays, Lobsters, Tuna, Squid, Pufferfish, Eels, and Koi Fish.

[image: Caught fish]